# how to pass mysql result to variable to render in template engines

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, node-modules

I want to store mysql result to a variable, so i can pass to the template engine. I have multiple mysql queries and need to save every query result to different variables.
I am using Node JS and express JS

Below is my code (app.js)

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'my_db'
});

db.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Database connected');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var emp_result;
    var task_list_result;

    db.query('SELECT * FROM emp',  function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;    

      emp_result = results;   

    });

    db.query('SELECT * FROM task_list',  function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;

      task_list_result;
    });

    res.render('dashboard',{"emp_res" : emp_result, "task_res" : task_list_result});
});
```

I am expecting that result should be store in a variable;

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Using async await here to handle the asynchronous network calls. I f you want to use callback function, you should chain it one inside the other.

```
const {promisify} = require('util');
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const query = promisify(db.query).bind(db);
  const emp_result = await db.query('SELECT * FROM emp')
  const task_list_result = await db.query('SELECT * FROM task_list')
  res.render('dashboard',{"emp_res" : emp_result, "task_res" : task_list_result});
});
```

Using Promise.all to make calls in parallel, as they are not dependent on each other, it increases the performance, you can use the below code-

```
const {promisify} = require('util');
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const query = promisify(db.query).bind(db);
  const [emp_result, task_list_result] = await Promise.all([db.query('SELECT * FROM emp'), db.query('SELECT * FROM task_list')]);
  res.render('dashboard',{"emp_res" : emp_result, "task_res" : task_list_result});
});
```

Using callback function, as you were using -

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM emp',  function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;    
    const emp_result = results; 
    db.query('SELECT * FROM task_list',  function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      const task_list_result = results;
      res.render('dashboard',{"emp_res" : emp_result, "task_res" : task_list_result});
    }); 
  });
});
```

You can use any of these, but second one is the best approach to follow.

Comment: on browser its showing [object Object]
my column name is pname
so m trying to fetch result on view <%= task_res[0].pname %>
but i m not getting result
@nayan patel